# How to take Offline Assignments in a Local Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

### Taking Offline assignments in Jupyter Notebooks

---

VSCODE  v. 1.46.1 | Python  v3.8.2 | Jupyter Notebook v. 6.0.3

I am trying to build a course with jupyter notebook wherein I'm interested to give a assignments at point after the course within the notebook. I want the notebook to be interactive with the students while they run it. To develop this I'm using VSCODE.

> Interested people can join the private project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Mynkxb)

I have used [*ipywidgets*](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html) to make my Notebooks interactive.

---

## **Problems Faced :**

#### Able to develop questions but cannot see output

MCQ Definition Cell

```
##Basic mcq
from ipywidgets import widgets, Layout, Box, GridspecLayout

def create_multipleChoice_widget(description, options, correct_answer, hint):
    if correct_answer not in options:
        options.append(correct_answer)
    
    correct_answer_index = options.index(correct_answer)
    
    radio_options = [(words, i) for i, words in enumerate(options)]
    alternativ = widgets.RadioButtons(
        options = radio_options,
        description = '',
        disabled = False,
        indent = False,
        align = 'center',
    )
    
    description_out = widgets.Output(layout=Layout(width='auto'))
    
    with description_out:
        print(description)
        
    feedback_out = widgets.Output()

    def check_selection(b):
        a = int(alternativ.value)
        if a==correct_answer_index:
            s = '\x1b[6;30;42m' + "correct" + '\x1b[0m' +"\n"
        else:
            s = '\x1b[5;30;41m' + "try again" + '\x1b[0m' +"\n"
        with feedback_out:
            feedback_out.clear_output()
            print(s)
        return
    
    check = widgets.Button(description="check")
    check.on_click(check_selection)
    
    hint_out = widgets.Output()
    
    def hint_selection(b):
        with hint_out:
            print(hint)
            
        with feedback_out:
            feedback_out.clear_output()
            print(hint)
    
    hintbutton = widgets.Button(description="hint")
    hintbutton.on_click(hint_selection)
    
    return widgets.VBox([description_out, 
                         alternativ, 
                         widgets.HBox([hintbutton, check]), feedback_out], 
                        layout=Layout(display='flex',
                                     flex_flow='column',
                                     align_items='stretch',
                                     width='auto'))
```

Question Cell :

```
test = create_multipleChoice_widget('1.What version of Python is used throughout this course?',['1.x','2.x','2.7','3.x'],'3.x','[hint]: Refer Lesson Again')
```

Output Cell :

[image: Output Cell Must Show Radio Buttons]

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually display the object. Putting this into the next cell works:

[image]